# Datalist suggestions show for unrelated textarea in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, textarea, html-datalist

Ok, the `div` with the issue is this.

```
<table id="torFormContainer">
            <tbody><tr>
                <th colspan="2">
                    New Time Off Request
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="supebox">
                <td>
                    *Supervisor:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input name="supe" id="supe" type="text" list="supes" required="">
                    <datalist id="supes">
<option value="Ashley Helms">
    </option><option value="Dan Boling">
    </option><option value="Daniel Jenkins">
    </option><option value="Hannah Amos">
    </option><option value="Keith Underwood">
    </option><option value="Shane Smith">
    </option><option value="Wade Horton">
    </option></datalist>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="sdatebox">
                <td class="left">
                    *Start Date:
                </td>
                <td class="right">
                    <input type="date" id="sdate" name="sdate" min="2014-06-11" onblur="testSdate();" onchange="testSdate();" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="edatebox">
                <td class="left">
                    *End Date:
                </td>
                <td class="right">
                    <input id="edate" name="edate" type="date" onblur="testEdate();" onchange="testEdate();" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="reasonbox">
                <td class="left">
                    *Reason:
                </td>
                <td class="right">
                    <select id="reason" name="reason" required="">
                        <option value="0" disabled="true">Select a Reason</option>
                        <option value="3">Comp</option>
<option value="6">Death in Family</option>
<option value="4">Family Leave</option>
<option value="5">Personal Leave</option>
<option value="2">Sickness</option>
<option value="1">Vacation</option>

                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Comment:
                </td>
                <td>
                    <textarea id="comment" placeholder="Optional" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left" id="required">
                    *Required
                </td>
                <td id="submit">
                    <input id="torSub" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="torPreSubmit();">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

For some reason, and as far as I can see, only in Chrome, after doing the supervisor name, the textarea also shows the list of suggestions from the supervisor list. Now, it may very well be something stupid that I've overlooked, and there is some jquery checking on the dates and etc, but I can't for the life of me figure this out. Some of the jquery below.

```
    function torPreSubmit(){    
        var submit = true;
        if($('#sdate').val()===""){
            $('#sdatebox').css('outline','thin solid red');
            console.log("sdate fail");
            submit = false;
        }else{
            console.log("sdate pass");
            $('#sdatebox').css('outline','');
        }
        if($('#edate').val()===""){
            $('#edatebox').css('outline','thin solid red');
            console.log("edate fail");
            submit = false;
        }else{
            console.log("edate pass");
            $('#edatebox').css('outline','');
        }
        if($('#supe').val()===""){
            $('#supebox').css('outline','thin solid red');
            console.log("supe fail");
            submit = false;
        }else{
            console.log("supe pass");
            $('#supebox').css('outline','');
        }
        if($('#reason').val()===null){
            console.log("reason fail");
            $('#reasonbox').css('outline','thin solid red');
            submit = false;
        }else{
            console.log("reason pass");
            $('#reasonbox').css('outline','');
        }
        if(submit){
            torSubmit();
            $('#reasonbox').css('outline','');
            $('#edatebox').css('outline','');
            $('#sdatebox').css('outline','');
        }
    }

function testSdate(){
    $("#edate").val('');
    if(Date.parse($("#sdate").val())<=Date.today()){
        $('#sdate').val('');
    }else{
        $('#edate').attr('min',$("#sdate").val());
    }
}

function testEdate(){
    if((Date.parse($("#edate").val())<Date.today())||(Date.parse($("#edate").val())<Date.parse($("#sdate").val())) ){
        $('#edate').val('');
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug in the chrome browser. No datalist for me lol

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest you to check for the version of the chrome browser, data lists have issue with the browser version 35 and below.  They have fixed it in their beta release version 36, you will need to download from here https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/index.html?extra=betachannel#eula this will update your browser and the site will work smoothly...!!!

Hope this helps

Cheers..